# Using Intent in Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am currently learning Android app development and I am a bit confused on how to use `Intent`. I am trying to make a "To Do list" app. My problem right now is that I want to be able to tap the item in my to do list to go to a `Edit Item` page.

Here is what I have so far.

ToDoActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_to_do);
    etNewItem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNewItem);
    lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);        // now we have access to ListView
    readItems();        // read items from file
    todoAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, todoItems);   //create adapter
    lvItems.setAdapter(todoAdapter);        // populate listview using the adapter 
    setupListViewListener();
    setupEditItemListener();

}
```

The activity I want to launch is called `EditItemListener`. These are the two functions that I am playing `Intent` with. Right now I am just testing how to display the EditItemActivity.

```
private void launchEditItem() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, EditItemActivity);
    startActivity(i);
}


private void setupEditItemListener() {          // on click, run this function to display edit page
    lvItems.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            launchEditItem();
        }   
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should specify it as a class

`Intent i = new Intent(this, EditItemActivity.class);`

Also if you want to kill the current activity

use `finish()` after `StartActivity()`

Comment: Good answer except don't use `finish`. Let Android handle that.

Comment: @Arju I was reading around and I found somewhere that said if i wanted to go back to the original activity. I would use `finish()` in my second activity that my `Intent` linked to. Not sure what you mean by let Android handle it.

Comment: if you want to come back to this activity ,no need to use finish else you must release the resources held by your activity

Answer (score 1):

on a listview set the OnItemClickListener and on the listener do this

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class); //where you are (this) and where you  go (YourAcitivity.class)
startActivity(i); //Now GO!
```

The intent will start another activity, this activity must be declared on AndroidMainfest.xml